# Find where css class is applied to in mulitiple pages

Tags: css

I just got in a large company and given a task for writing CSS documentation. The CSS file is very large and I don't know how to understand specific css classes without looking at the visual element it applied to. Is there a way to find the css elements across different pages?

Comment: How about just doing a text search across all the files of the project?

Comment: by using a browser developer tool, when you inspect an element you can get the class and it's style

Comment: I can find the css class defination in css files, but just reading the class defination is really hard to understand what exactly it would look like in browser.  EX: .a {
 text-align:center;
 padding:@base-spacing*2 0;
 .make-row();
 & > div{
  .make-sm-column(6);
 }
}

Comment: @Drixson Oseña The problem is how do i know which element in which page this specific class is applied to? There are more than 100 pages

Comment: Are the classes applied dynamically (e.g. directly from the backend or by js), or is it more statically? The former one is a little bit harder, or at least you will need to use some complex tooling, but the latter should only require a text-search within the whole system for the class/id name.

Comment: In case of the former one I'm thinking of a tool similar to a web scrapper, which will go through the sitemap, load each and every page and do a lookup for the given class. Once found write the page url and element(s) to a file or log...

Comment: Look at this: https://metacpan.org/pod/Web::Scraper

Comment: Are you familiar with Chrome Developer Tools or Firefox Inspector?

Comment: You pasted code that is not pure css. First you have to compile the css from these files to generate the final css to preview.

Comment: @ Gabriel C. Troia, That link is helpful but is there any alternative tool without me doing coding stuff?